# convert between clause of sql to mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a table with name `OgShift` and I want to fetch all the records if current DateTime lies between `ShiftStartTime` and `ShiftEndTime`. It works perfectly fine in SQL but I need to implement it for `MongoDB` using `node and mongoose`.

here is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.OgShift 
WHERE '2018-12-18 04:43:59.810' BETWEEN ShiftStartTime AND ShiftEndTime
AND isActive=1
```

**Database collection**
[image]

**Schema**

```
let OgShift=new mongoose.Schema({
    ShiftName:String,
    ShiftStartTime:Date,
    ShiftEndTime:Date,
    isActive:Boolean    
})
```

**Route code**

```
app.get('/shift',async (req,res)=>{
    var ShiftStartTime = new Date(req.query.ShiftStartTime).toISOString();
    var ShiftEndTime = new Date(req.query.ShiftEndTime).toISOString();

    let result = await OgShift.OgShift.find({
        ShiftStartTime: {
            $gt: ShiftStartTime
        },
        ShiftEndTime: {
            $lt: ShiftEndTime
        }
    });
    res.send('ShiftStartTime is' + ShiftStartTime + " end date is " + ShiftEndTime + result);

})
```

**Result on Browser**
[image]
**Code after commenting the date filters**

```
app.get('/shift',async (req,res)=>{
    var ShiftStartTime = new Date(req.query.ShiftStartTime).toISOString();
    var ShiftEndTime = new Date(req.query.ShiftEndTime).toISOString();

    let result = await OgShift.OgShift.find({});
    res.send('ShiftStartTime is' + ShiftStartTime + " end date is " + ShiftEndTime + result);

})
```

**Result after commenting the filters**
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: what is your `datetime` field name in your Model schema ?

Comment: please add your model schema to question

Comment: The structure is the same as shared above in the SQL query.

Comment: so you want to get all shifts between `ShiftStartTime` and `ShiftEndTime` ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Yes, I do.

Comment: my answer is working or not ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I'm afraid your answer is not fetching data as required. I'm about to update the question and add more data too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185419/discussion-between-aay-que-and-saurabh-mistry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can not write the query in `SQL` way but have to do it in mongo way.
After a lot of tries, I finally succeed with below logic.

```
let result = await OgShift.OgShift.find({
        $and: [{
            isActive: true
            }
        }],
        $or: [{
                "ShiftStartTime": {
                    "$gte": start,
                    "$lte": end
                }
            },
            {
                "ShiftEndTime": {
                    "$gte": start,
                    "$lte": end
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

convert your input date to ISO format and then apply find query

make get request : `/find?ShiftStartTime='start_date'&ShiftEndTime='end_date'`

```
app.get('/find',function(req,res){

    var ShiftStartTime=new Date(req.query.ShiftStartTime).toISOString();
    var ShiftEndTime=new Date(req.query.ShiftEndTime).toISOString();

    OgShift.find({
       isActive:true,
       $and:[{
               ShiftStartTime:{$gte:ShiftStartTime}
             },
             {
              ShiftEndTime:{$lte:ShiftEndTime}
             }],       
    },function(err,result){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
      if(!err && result){
        return res.stauts(200).json({result:result});
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope this will work for you

```
let result = await OgShift.OgShift.find({
        ShiftStartTime: {
             $gte:new Date("2018-01-12"),
        },
        ShiftEndTime: {
            $lt: new Date("2019-12-31")
        }
    })
```